# Can a pdfbox or itextsharp or pdfsharp reads corrupted pdf file

Tags: c#, parsing, itext, pdfsharp

I recently downloaded pdf libraries ( pdfbox, pdfsharp, itextsharp), and I am trying to figure out can i parse corrupted pdf files with in Asp.Net.
which lib is best for reading corrupted pdf file.

Comment: In which way are the files corrupt? I would not expect any library to be able to read a file with a format that does not adhere to the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is corrupt, there is no guaranteed way to read it.  You cannot know which part or parts are corrupt.  You could use a hex editor utility and manually inspect which parts might be corrupted, but there is no way to use any of the libraries you mentioned to open a corrupted file.  They all work off the PDF specification, which assumes a valid PDF file.